# setContentOffset: animated: wont do anything if animated = NO

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm trying to scroll to the last viewed position of a PDF that's being viewed in a webView. When the PDF is unloaded, it will save the y offset of the webView's scrollView. Then when the PDF is re-opened, I would like to jump to where they left off.

The below code works fine when animated is set to YES, however when it's set to NO, nothing happens

```
    float scrollPos = [[settingsData objectForKey:kSettingsScrollPosition]floatValue];
    NSLog(@"scrolling to %f",scrollPos);
    [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollPos) animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"ContentOffset:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(webView.scrollView.contentOffset));
```

this outputs:

**scrolling to 5432.000000**

**CO:{0, 5432}**

However the PDF is still displaying the top page

I have viewed the answers on similar questions here but they dont solve this problem.

Thanks for  the help :)

Comment: Have you tried calling `setNeedsDisplay`?  Just a thought.  Or what it you set the offset to one pixel shy of the desired without animation, and then animate the one pixel movement to the desired position.  Does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

You can't touch `contentOffset` before `UIWebView` component has done the rendering of the PDF. It works for `setContentOffset: animated:YES` because the animation forces the rendering.

If you set `contentOffset` to at least 0.3s (from my test) after the rendering starts, there is no problem at all.

For instance if you load the PDF in the `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController` you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` in your `viewDidAppear:` to delay `contentOffset` setting.

To hide the PDF before `contentOffset` is set, you can set its alpha to 0.01 (don't set it to 0 unless rendering would not start) and set it back to 1 after you set `contentOffset`.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *w;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *w;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize w;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *u = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"pdf"];
    [w loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:u]];
    w.alpha = 0.01f;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjust) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
}

- (void)adjust
{
    float scrollPos = 800;
    NSLog(@"scrolling to %f",scrollPos);
    [w.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollPos) animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"ContentOffset:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(w.scrollView.contentOffset));
    w.alpha = 1;
}

@end
```